# R Shiny Architecture Model

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

```
I am trying to understand Shiny's architecture, but I don't understand how the following       code executes:




   library(shiny)

      ui <- fluidPage(
      
        wellPanel(sliderInput("number","input number" , value=10,min=1,max=20)),
        wellPanel(textOutput("out1")),
      )
  
      server <- function(input, output) {
         
        X <- 42
        Y <- 1123
          print(c("    Hello X = ",X," Y = ",Y))
          
           output$out1 <-  renderText(  {
           
               X <- X+1
               print(c("input = ",input$number))
               print(c(" X = ",X))
               print(c(" Y = ",Y))
               })  
           X <- X+1
           Y <- Y+1
      print(c("Good Bye, X = ",X, " Y = ",Y))
       }    

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output (on the console) is like this:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5522
[1] "    Hello X = " "42"             " Y = "          "1123"          
[1] "Good Bye, X = " "43"             " Y = "          "1124"          
[1] "input = " "10"      
[1] " X = " "44"   
[1] " Y = " "1124" 
[1] "input = " "8"               (having moved the slider)      
[1] " X = " "44"   
[1] " Y = " "1124"
```

My thought was that the server function would run from beginning to end. That is verified by the first two lines of output. The reactive part (renderText) is not executed (no output) during the execution of "server".

My thought was that while the server function executed a thread was spun off that is alerted when the slider changes. That thread sees the enclosing server environment.This hypothesized thread would be notified when I moved the slider from 10 to 8. However the reactive context doesn't increment X to 45. Why?? My expectation is that X would keep incrementing by 2 as I move the slider.

The reactive context clearly sees Y in its environment (no error thrown by the print statement but it doesn't see X. ( I understand that incrementing X in the global environment requires <<- instead of <- .

To make matters more confusing, the slider works just fine but all I see (besides the slider panel) is the printout "Y=124". What happened to "X" ? It should be printing out also (presumably with a new value).

Try to execute the code and move the slider and see how the system state doesn't seem to change.

Any help appreciated. I am new to Shiny and probably being dense....

Comment: X should be a `reactiveVal`, see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.0/reactiveVal.html

Answer (score 0):

These are created when the server function is run once. The server sets up the server-side part of the shiny app. After that it won't be run again. `renderText` sets a a reactive environment but that is not evaluated until you move the slider which is the only reactive dependency that this `renderText` has. That is why `X` and `Y` have increased once to `X = 43` and `Y = 1124`.

Before this runs, `X = 42` and `Y = 1123`.

```
[1] "    Hello X = " "42"             " Y = "          "1123"
[1] "Good Bye, X = " "43"             " Y = "          "1124"
```

After: `X = 43` and `Y = 1124`.

Then first move of the slider:

```
[1] "input = " "10"      
[1] " X = " "44"   
[1] " Y = " "1124"
```

Now, the `renderText` is called when the slider is initialised with `10`. Please note, only `renderText` runs **not** the whole server function. It certainly finds `X`. But - as you correctly stated - the `<-` assignment does not change the "global" `X` of the server function. Instead it takes the global `X` adds 1 and assigns it to a new local variable `X`. That local `X` will be forgotten when `renderText` finishes. `Y` is left alone which is why you get `X = 44` and `Y = 1124`. The global `X` is still `43`.

The text box in the UI that is fed by `renderText` will only show `Y` because that is the last expression in it. Like R functions, the last evaluated expression is returned automatically. In your case the result of `Y <- Y+1`. IF you want both place `paste("X =", X, "- Y =", Y)` as last statement or use the explicit `return()` function.

Now you repeat the same thing. Since the local `X` did not persist and has been lost since the last run of `renderText` you get the exact same result as before (except for `input$number`, of course).

```
[1] "input = " "8"               (having moved the slider)      
[1] " X = " "44"   
[1] " Y = " "1124"
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for the thoughtful reply. I still have one question: when I run the code the Viewer shows the slider and has a text output box that only contains "Y=1125".